# Codeigniter: How to get result() for Transactions

Tags: php, postgresql, codeigniter, model, transactions

My setup is: codeigniter+postgresql.

Here is an example from official CI user guide about using [Transactions](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/transactions.html):

```
$this->db->trans_start();
$this->db->query('AN SQL QUERY...');
$this->db->query('ANOTHER QUERY...');
$this->db->query('AND YET ANOTHER QUERY...');
$this->db->trans_complete();
```

My transaction returns a value (INSERT ... RETURNING some_id).
**Question:** how can I assign this some_id to a variable in php (CI)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just like you would for a SELECT query - call `result()` on the object returned by `query()`.

Transactions are irrelevant to this.

Comment: Thx for answer. Can you please share a simple example?

Comment: `$this->db->query('INSERT INTO ... RETURNING some_id')->result()` ... seriously, if you read at all what I wrote you wouldn't need an example.

Comment: `$this->db->trans_start();
$this->db->query('UPDATE table1...');
$some_id = $this->db->query('INSERT INTO table2 ... RETURNING some_id')->result();
$this->db->query('UPDATE table1...');
$this->db->trans_complete();
`
this code returns error:
_Call to a member function result() on a non-object_

Comment: That means that your query has failed ... or that you're using an outdated CodeIgniter version. Although, by the way you've written that, it's obvious that you also don't know how `result()` works; you should read the [documentation](http://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/results.html) too.

Comment: I'm using CI 3 and yes — i'm newbie in CI. I've found the cause of a problem, It's about my PostgreSQL query: I'm using `INSERT...RETURNING` and, as I understand - in case if we are using insert, CI returns only boolean (true/false), that's why it's not an object. Instead of "RETURNING" I'll use `SELECT lastval() as some_id;`. That's all, @Narf :)

Comment: 3 is just the major version number ... it doesn't tell the whole story. `query()` is supposed to return results sets for `INSERT ... RETRUNING` statements, but there was a *bug* that was preventing this from happening and it was fixed in version 3.0.4 - you're obviously running a version older than that. :)

Comment: `echo CI_VERSION;` — 3.0.4  :)  interesting.

Comment: Then the query is failing. :)

Comment: Maybe you are right, because i'm using query with structure like this `INSERT ... SELECT... RETURNING some_id`
anyway, thx for help, Narf, I don't want to violate stackoverflows` rules about "avoid extended discussions in comments" :)